# optimising aggregates with and without a condition in ms sql

Tags: sql, optimization, refactoring, aggregate

I would like to get a sum from a column, with and without a condition. The code I have now is

```
SELECT regular.id, regular.sum as regularsum, special.sum as specialsum FROM 
(SELECT Sum(stuff) as sum, id FROM table
 WHERE commonCondition = true
 GROUP BY id) as regular
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Sum(stuff) as sum, id FROM table
 Where commonCondition = true AND specialCondition = true
 GROUP BY id) as special
ON regular.id = special.id
```

Which works, but seems very inefficient, not to mention ugly. the table is fairly large, so some optimisation would be welcome.

How can I write this in a better, more efficent way?

Comment: do u have any indexes on the table?

Comment: There is an index on id and on specialCondition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do something like this:

```
 SELECT 
    Sum(stuff) as regularsum, 
    sum(case when specialcondition=true then stuff else 0 end) as specialsum,
    id FROM table
 WHERE commonCondition = true
 GROUP BY id
```

However, you'd want to test to see if it was any faster.

Comment: Execution time went down from 98783 millies to 58631 millies, not to mention this is much neater code. Thanks!

Comment: Just for the records, though this statement is what I meant, the two statements aren't identical: this statement does include rows where specialcondition = false for all cases, and the original statement doesnt. A Left Outer Join with an isnull(specialSum, 0) in the  original would make them identical